# React Native Stripe Xcode 14 Build Failed

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments, stripes, xcode14

"@stripe/stripe-react-native": "^0.2.3"

[image: 1]

I hope you are doing well. I face a problem when i try to run build on xcode 14.1 (Beta Version).

**Build failed due to react native stripe package. Bug occur in CardDetailsEditView.swift file
(Stored properties cannot be marked potentially unavailable with '@available').
**

I waste my 2-3 days to solve this bug but all is vain. Can you please help me what i need to do change in my file for a successful build.

Thanks in advance.

I change pod file version from 11 to 12.4 12 13 and 14 but not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion in this github [issue](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/issues/1212). It looks like you need to use an older version of xcode to avoid this error.

Comment: Not Working. Thanks

Comment: have you solved this error?